# How to use PrintWriter with Java 6 under MacOS X 10.10.5 to disable buffering?

Tags: java, macos, eclipse-kepler

I am having a problem with the Java Compiler v6.0 with Eclipse Kepler under MacOS X 10.10.5 to support the autoFlush option for the Java PrintWriter command.  If I supply a boolean to enable the "autoFlush", per the Java Docs for Java 6.0, Eclipse claims it's an illegal parameter.  Yet, when I verified my Compiler settings under Eclipse, it does say Java 1.6.0 for Compiler Complaince Level.  So, why does Eclipse or the Compiler fail to recognize the boolean parameter for "autoFlush?"

Here is the code:

```
DrawingPanel.logFile = new PrintWriter("LogFile.txt", true); <-- Eclipse does not like the "true" argument.
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#constructor_summary) has 8 constructors:

```
PrintWriter(File file)
PrintWriter(File file, String csn)
PrintWriter(OutputStream out)
PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)
PrintWriter(String fileName)
PrintWriter(String fileName, String csn)
PrintWriter(Writer out)
PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush)
```

Only the `OutputStream` and `Writer` versions have an `autoFlush` second argument. The compiler is correctly complaining that your second argument is not a `String`.

You should use:

```
DrawingPanel.logFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("LogFile.txt"), true)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that!